# flutter: I have using firebase auth with provider. Its working fine in debug but app crashes in release

Tags: flutter, dart

I am try to create release apk, but when release apk and run my release device it crashes but in debug it working find can you . I have checked and issue in my firebase auth  code. Can anyone please help me out

main.dart code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  bool isFirstTime;
  ThemeData appTheme;

  MyApp(bool isFirstTime,ThemeData appTheme) {
    this.isFirstTime = isFirstTime;
    this.appTheme=appTheme;
  }
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<UserModel>.value(
          value: Auth().onAuthStateChanged,
        ),
        Provider<Database>(create: (_)=>RealtimeDatabase(),),

        Provider<AuthBase>(create: (_)=>Auth(),),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: UserAddressesViewModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: GoogleMapsFindAddressModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: SelectAddressViewModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: AppThemeViewModel(appTheme))

      ],
      child: CMaterialAppWidget(isFirstTime: isFirstTime,),
    );
  }
}
```

auth class

```
UserModel _userFromFirebase(User user,UserType userType) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }





    return UserModel(
        uid: user.uid,
        name: user.displayName,
        userImage: user.photoURL,
        userType: userType,
      phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber
    );
  }

  @override
  Stream<UserModel> get onAuthStateChanged {

    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map((event){
      if(event.isAnonymous!=null){
        return _userFromFirebase(event, event.isAnonymous?UserType.guest:UserType.standard);

      }else{
        return _userFromFirebase(event, UserType.guest);
      }
    });
```

build gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.hellowcity"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 4
        versionName '1.3'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0-beta03'

}
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added sha key to your Firebase Console?

Note: sha key for debug and release is different

you can find your key with ./android/gradlew signingReport

Comment: if you have added sha for release key to your firebase, try remove signingConfig signingConfigs.debug on your build.gradle